# Why is it that in the movie Cinderella the horse is transformed into the driver?

Tags: plot-explanation, cinderella-1950

I loved seeing the movie Cinderella but I am confused about why the fairy God mother changed the horse to a carriage driver?  Isn't the horse strong enough?

Answer (score 3):

Because it's funny. The horse expected to be the one to pull the magic carriage. Instead he's the driver and the mice are the horses.

Answer (score 2):

It probably looked more majestic to have the carriage pulled by 4 horses instead of one and of course only one driver was required. There were 4 mice and one horse. Ergo...

Comment: Yeah the Disney rendition involved four mice that were transformed into horses to pull the carriage.  I know the movie is magical and it definitely is to entertain.  I was curious if there was any logical reason.

Comment: Isnt the above reason logical enough? 4 mice = 4 horses. As @Catija mentioned, horses are usually paired when pulling carriages so she needed at least 2. It wouldn't have looked very graceful transforming Major into a ever better looking horse, transforming only 3 mice to the remaining 3, and then transforming the last mice to a driver.

Comment: That's true. I do like the fact it looks more majestic.  The prince might not have started to court her if she only had one horse. :)

Comment: @RyanRammell: My sarcasm senses are tingling.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Having four friends, (mice), pull the carriage not only saved time, but also ensured a sense of comradery and teamwork amongst the team.

Additionally, it ensures a pleasant evening to have a mute carriage driver. Had one of the mice, who can speak, become the carriage driver, they would have talked Cinderella to death. But by having a friendly and albeit dim-witted person in the lead, as well as the talking characters people rendered unable to talk, you have an ideal and quiet evening.

I suppose you could also say that it's far from graceful to have an ass of a horse changed into a more majestic horse... that sends a bad message about beauty discrimination.